# Linq to XML - Read/Parse only first lines of the file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Is it possible to parse only part of an xml-file using LINQ to XML?

Let's take the following file as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<FileWithData>
    <Header>
        <Type>File</Type>
        <Content>Data</Content>
    </Header>
    <TonsOfData>
        .......
    </TonsOfData>
</FileWithData>
```

I would like to read the `Header` information from several of such files, however loading them with `XElement.Load(pathXmlFile)` and navigate to the `Header`-node takes quite some time. Is it possible to somehow parse only a subtree from my xml structure to speed things up?

Comment: It might be interesting to see how you do it now and why it does take some time.

Comment: It is *easy* to not load into the `XElement` the `TonsOfData` element... It is more complex to stop the `TonsOfData` from being read.

Comment: I don't mind "more complex". Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: Since you are reading from multiple files, your problem also feels like a good candidate for parallelization.

Comment: @Discosultan the calls are already made asynchronous :)

Comment: @HW Great! Combine that with what was suggested in the answer and you should be golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load to memory only header:

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathXmlFile))
{
    if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Header"))
    {
        XmlReader headerSubtree = xmlReader.ReadSubtree();
        XElement headerElement = XElement.Load(headerSubtree);

        // process headerElement
        Console.WriteLine(headerElement.Element("Type").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(headerElement.Element("Content").Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to use `XElement.ReadFrom` because you are reading a fragment.

Comment: What is the difference of `XElement.ReadFrom` to the suggested solution? The above code works fine for me :)

Comment: @HW I wasn't using `ReadSubtree`, so I had an exception... You can do `ReadSubtree` + `Load` or use directly `ReadFrom`

Comment: @xanatos ReadFrom returns XNode, Load returns XElement. It's more convenient, I think.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov If you know that you are reading an element, you can cast the result to `XElement` without problem.

Answer (score 0):

XDocument and XElement read everything into memory, I think you need to use an XMLReader, not Linq to XML.